# What does PHPDoc "static" return type signify here?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpstorm, phpdoc

I am working on a Symfony project with entities managed by Doctrine. The following is code from my entity:

```
class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Appointment", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $appointments;

    /**
     * Get appointments
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getAppointments()
    {
        return $this->appointments;
    }

    /**
     * Get appointments at a specified date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|static
     */
    public function getAppointmentsAtDate(\DateTime $date) {
        $allAppointments = $this->getAppointments();

        $criteria = Criteria::create()->where(/* some clever filtering logic goes here */);

        return $allAppointments ->matching($criteria);
    }
}
```

`getAppointments` is auto-generated by Doctrine. The `getAppointmentsAtDate` method was implemented by myself. The method's PHPDoc header was auto-generated by PhpStorm.

What I cannot understand is the `static` keyword in my custom method's return type.

From my understanding of the [PHPDoc types](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/types.html) `static` signifies that this method returns an instance of the class on which it was called, in this case a `User` instance.

However, I fail to see how this method could ever return a `User` instance or anything other than an instance of `Collection`.

So what does the `static` keyword mean here? Is my understanding of the keyword flawed? Or is PhpStorm's auto-generated documentation header simply wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have looked at the source of doctrine for the [`matching` function](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/0e7729b8c0ec7d2345a4934c9b1f89fbb488b0b4/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php#L359) and here is the return type :

```
return new static($filtered);
```

Phpstorm probably parsed the doctrine source and saw the return static statement in the matching function.

Comment: Ok, but then this means that the generated return type is incorrect, right? Because the `matching` function returns a `static` object, which is some subclass of `Collection`, so my method will always return a `Collection` (or subclass), but never `User` or subclass.

Comment: Yes, the interpretation is incorrect ! You should remove the `|static` in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of the static keyword is correct.

Your code:

```
return $allAppointments ->matching($criteria);
```

Returns the results of the matching function, from the `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection` class, which returns:

```
return new static($filtered);
```

As you can see on line 385, of the file [`ArrayCollection.php`](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/0e7729b8c0ec7d2345a4934c9b1f89fbb488b0b4/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php#L385)

Which is probably where PHPStorm deduced the possible return type. The Code:

```
new static()
```

Would appear to PHPStorm to be returning a new instance of a static class. Probably not the correct interpretation, but you should see how an automated system would not necessarily know the difference between:

```
new someclass();
// and
new static();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of static keyword sounds correct.
PHPDoc of `matching` method says it returns `Collection`. Seems to me like PhpStorm made a mistake. Maybe you made some changes in code after it was generated?

Comment: To test your hypothesis, I have just deleted the documentation header and it was still re-generated with the same return type.